# Properly rendering multiple layouts per controller in Rails

Tags: layout, view, ruby-on-rails-3.1, render

I've defined in my **Users_controller**:

`layout "intro", only: [:new, :create]`

Here's what my layout looks like: 
**Intro.html.haml**

```
!!! 5
%html{lang:"en"}
%head
  %title Intro
  = stylesheet_link_tag    "application", :media => "all"
  = javascript_include_tag "application"
  = csrf_meta_tags
%body{style:"margin: 0"}
  %header
    = yield
  %footer= debug(params)
```

When I render a page that calls for `intro` as the layout, it gets nested inside my `application.html.haml` file which is not good.

Is there some way of avoiding this undesirable nesting of layouts?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 54, accepted):

The problem was in my Controller.  I was declaring multiple layout instances like so:

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  layout "intro", only: [:new, :create]
  layout "full_page", only: [:show]
  ...
end
```

**Don't do this!**  The second declaration will take precedence and you won't get your desired affect.

Instead, if your layouts are simply action-specific, just declare it within the action like this:

```
def show
...
render layout: "full_page"
end
```

Or, if it's a bit more complex, you can use a symbol to defer the processing to a method at runtime like this:

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  layout :determine_layout
  ...

  private
    def determine_layout
      @current_user.admin? ? "admin" : "normal"
    end
end
```